# WebView wrap_content doesn't occupy entire view size

Tags: android, webview, android-constraintlayout

Inside a ConstraintLayout I have a webview with layout_height and layout_width set to wrap_content, and many constraints to maintain the webview in the center, with an aspect ratio of 9:16 and a max height of 720dp. The problem is  that the webview doesn't seem to fill the entire screen size assigned to it, leaving a remaining space at the bottom.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fl_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_telcel_landing_tablet"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarWeb"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webContent"
            android:background="?attr/image_background_landing"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_max="720dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="9:16"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

If I use a fixed height and width for the webview, it uses all the space available, but it causes other kinds of problems like getting cut off at the top and the bottom in landscape.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fl_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_telcel_landing_tablet"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarWeb"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webContent"
        android:background="?attr/image_background_landing"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="405dp"
        android:layout_height="720dp"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

I've been trying all of these suggested solutions, but none of them worked.

```
webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
webview.setInitialScale(1);
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

> just changes webview width and height like below. You are giving wrap_content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fl_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarWeb"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webContent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_max="720dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="9:16"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```